# designate VS assign

Tags: word-meaning

> One naked, bald, vaguely female doll, made of hard shiny plastic, whom I **designated** the mother. I made her a Greek-style tunic out of an old handkerchief and glued a lock of my own hair to her head.
>
> Two tiny baby dolls of unidentified gender, made of hard, matte plastic, and wrapped in blankets of the same kind of plastic.
>
> And one hedgehog with a human body, dressed in a long skirt and apron, with tight, curly hair covered with a kerchief, to whom I **assigned** the role of grandmother.

I would like to translate this into my mother language persian, and I have difficulty choosing two different words instead of **assign** and **designate**. Could you provide me with some more English equivalent or synonyms for each one in this passage, please? Thank you a thousand times in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- **gave the role** of mother/grandmother.

this is basic

- **delegated as** the mother/grandmother.

This personifies the doll a little more. Often delegates are associated with politics but this is not exclusive; it generally gives a sense of earned authority.

- **authorized** to be the mother/grandmother.

Similar to above but doesn't have that looming political feel.

These are just a few quick ones. I am thinking you just need a few alternatives to kick-start your translating.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just simply use "chose to be the mother/grandmother" in this context. Since you are limiting the number of choices of people to family, choosing a role out of a number of possible roles gives you the option to use choose or chose. This is also just another option of words to add to the list of possibilities.